# Why are Google Play installation stats so inaccurate?

Tags: android, google-play

I noticed a large discrepancy in the stats reported by Google Play.  When I subtract totals for two consecutive days (Total User Installs).  I almost never get the same answer when I compare it to the Daily User Installs column? Do you know why it happens?  I posted my data [here](http://artymiak.com/can-you-trust-google-play-statistics/).

Comment: Use google analytics for mobile. Tge dev console is delayed all the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Play statistics are notoriously inaccurate. It is far better to use a service like [Google Analytics for Mobile](http://www.google.com/analytics/features/mobile.html) or [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/) to track your app usage. Both of these are far more accurate than Google Play. The Google Play statistics are so bad that you could probably create your own analytics and end up with better data.

Comment: It's now 2017. Is this still true.

Comment: Even in 2023 this is true.